# How to query using LINQ for EF6, Database First approach with Many to Many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am new to Entity Framework and trying to join three tables, `NT_Schedule`, `NT_Asset` and `NT_REL_Schedule_Asset` using LINQ. But I am not able to do so. Below are the three tables:
Can you please help?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some information what you have tried already?
Maybe you should read following [MS doc articel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

Comment: Maybe you mean something like:
`await _dbContext.NT_ASSET.Include(asset => asset.NT_REL_SCHEDULE_ASSET).ThenInclude(x => x.NT_SCHEDULE).ToListAsync();`